# Use /etc/profile settings for passwordless user

Tags: bash, permissions, etc

I'm having a small issue. I have a passwordless user (jenkins) on a Unix system. This user is used by jenkins to perform some commands.
Because I installed nvm on this unix system, I needed to add to `/etc/profile` a section to let the users know where the binary is.

By executing

```
sudo -u jenkins nvm
```

I get following error:

```
[USER@HOST ~]$ sudo -u jenkins nvm
/bin/nvm: line 6: /bin/nvm.sh: No such file or directory
```

For any other user this setting works, but not for the jenkins user. The jenkins user does not have its own home directory in /home folder. Therefore, I guess that's the reason why it's not working for it.

How can I apply these settings to the jenkins user?

```
Linux xx 3.10.0-957.21.3.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Jun 14 02:54:29 EDT 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: It looks that `nvm` is starting correctly but there is no `/bin/nvm.sh`. Can you show output of `ls -Alht /bin/nvm.sh`?

Comment: Output: ls -Alht /bin/nvm.sh
ls: cannot access /bin/nvm.sh: No such file or directory
I made a link from /bin/nvm to /usr/local/lib/.nvm/nvm-exec. But in /etc/profile I configured that the nvm.sh is in the path I mentioned before.

/etc/profile:

#NVM
export NVM_DIR="/usr/local/lib/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion

But this does not affec the jenkins user.

Comment: You can use bacticks to format code in the comment section as well. Why is `nvm` trying to access `/bin/nvm.sh` specifically then? Can you post `/bin/nvm`?

Comment: Better yet, [edit] your question to include all relevant / necessary information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to have the shell read and execute commands from `/etc/profile`, `/etc/bashrc` and the like when switching users with `sudo`, you probably need to use the `-i` or `--login` option, i.e. `sudo -i -u jenkins nvm`.